# Custom Shaped Textarea in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, textarea, customization

Is it possible to have custom shaped text areas in HTML/CSS (Textarea that has more than 4 edges)? How?
Something like this:
[image]
OR if possible;something more complex like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I shudder in the act of giving this link, because it's super un-semantic. You end up with tons of divs whose only purpose is to create "wrapping points" for the text.

But, FWIW, here's how you could do what you're asking. I would personally only do something like this for the fun of it or maybe on my own site, but probably not any other production public site.

http://www.csstextwrap.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is a super old question but still shows up high in google, so here's the answer you're probably looking for today: [shape-outside](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/shapes/getting-started/). *(If you don't care about IE or edge)*

Sadly there is no shape-inside for the hexagon example but it can be achieved with a shape-outside on both sides as described later in the linked article.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For the top result, if you have a the following html you should get something like what you are looking for

```
<div style="width:'textbox-width';">
    <img  style="float: right" />
    <span>text goes here</span>
</div>
```

where the image is a blank spacer of the size you require, then the text in the span should wrap around the image and appear as above.

The hexagon might be possible using the same method with triangluar images

Comment: Is there really a such thing as a "triangular image"? I think no matter what an image is rectangular. It might be an image of a triangle, but the image itself is a rectangle. gif and png images can have transparency, but not really different edges. Perhaps a css3 transform could cause an image to render with angles?

Comment: True, I didn't really think that through all the way. Possibly possible if you used a selection of different width images on top of each other, giving the impressions of triangular images. Might be more hassle than it is worth tho

Answer (score 0):

I might become possible in the future with CSS3 Regions and Wrap Shapes (proposed by Adobe):
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/css3-regions.html